# Biconditional While Loop in x86 Assembly

Tags: loops, assembly, while-loop, x86, conditional-statements

Suppose I have a while loop in High Level Language that looks something like:

While i >= 0 and x < 5,

how would the assembly code in x86 look? I've tried thinking of using cmp for the conditional parts of the while statement, but I'm not sure how the AND would be implemented.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ;; assuming eax contains i, ecx contains x
myloop:
    test eax, eax
    jl   exitloop  ; i < 0
    cmp  ecx, 5
    jge  exitloop  ; x >= 5
    ;; loop content goes here
    jmp myloop
exitloop:
    ;; life continues after the loop
```

Comment: So if it's an AND statement, then it doesn't matter because if either statement is false it exits the loop, what if it were an OR instead of an AND? how would it be different?

Comment: You would change the jl to a jge and its target address to a label placed just after the second jge.